# RAII XmlWriter VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net, raii

I'm just picking up VB, so this is probably a noob question. Apologies in advance.

I'm trying to wrap an XmlWriter with a class to manage memory, flushing, closing etc... so that clients don't need to worry about it.

My code is:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off

Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO


Module MainModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim xmltest As XmlOutput = New XmlOutput("output.xml", "test")
        xmltest.writeData("hello", "19.95")
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class XmlOutput

    Private xmlWriter As XmlWriter

    Public Sub New(ByVal filename As String, ByVal calculator As String)
        xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename)
        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(True)
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement(calculator)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
        xmlWriter.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub writeData(ByVal head As String, ByVal value As String)
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString(head, value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232798
  Message=Cannot access a closed file.
  ObjectName=""
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
       at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Flush()
       at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Close()
       at System.Xml.XmlRawWriter.Close(WriteState currentState)
       at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.Close()
       at System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose()
       at XmlOutputTest.XmlOutput.Finalize()
  InnerException:
```

This looks like the XmlWriter has closed the FileStream before the XmlWriter is closed. Since the XmlWriter has responsibility for the FileStream I expected it to know when the FileStream had been closed.

*Questions:*

1. Why is the XmlWriter trying to close something it's already closed (or maybe I'm interpreting the stack trace incorrectly)?
2. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: This is *not* an improvement.  You cannot use a finalizer, you have no guarantee that the underlying FileStream isn't already finalized.  Well, you do now :)  Implement IDisposable instead.  In general, deciding whether or not to override Finalize() is pretty simple.  If you think it might be useful then you'll be wrong 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Thanks Hans, happy to accept that as an answer if you could provide a link so something that explains why that is the case. Also: my understanding is that iDisposable gives responsibility for memory management to clients of the object. Is it the case that doing this over using RAII is a VB idiom?